# Gemstones in Islam?

Tags: quran, sunnah

I encountered few people wearing gems like ruby(Yaqoot), coral(Marjan), Turquoise(Feroza) and some other gemstones and asked about it

- Why you wear it ?
- Did prophet wore that ?
- Does that have effect on human life ? if yes how and why ?

and got different answers 
Like

- Its mentioned in Quran
- Its Sunnah
- Those have Effect on human life (Do they ? )

Being a Muslim I want to know everything about it, what is the importance of those and how, why, I would appreciate if you use Quran and Hadith references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Its mentioned in Quran (?)*
  - only names of some gems are mentioned in the Quran, but there is no recommendation or prohibition about wearing it. (see [this](http://islamqa.info/en/33583))
- *Its sunnah (?)*

  > [It was narrated from Anas bin Malik](http://sunnah.com/urn/1278930) that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) wore a ring of silver, in which was an Ethiopian gemstone and the inscription: ‘Muhammad Rasul Allah’
- *Those have Effect on human life*
  Do they ? -**no**.

  > Say, "O Allah , Owner of Sovereignty,.....  In Your hand is [all] good... [[3:26](http://quran.com/3/26)]

I think, to believe that a material will bring fortune to human life is almost equivalent to shirk. So wear them only for decoration, but [do not show off](http://quran.com/4/38)